# Mac OS X launch application on custom url scheme

Tags: macos, qt, url

I'm trying to make my Mac OS X app to respond custom URL like myurl://foo.bar
I've added necessary lines to my Info.plist but it doesn't work: when I click on custom URL in browser it doesn't launch my app.

Below is my Info.plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>Remote Dialer</string>
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
<string>NSApplication</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string></string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
<string>Created by Qt/QMake</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>RemoteDialer</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.taxisoft.RemoteDialer</string>
<key>NOTE</key>
<string>This file was generated by Qt/QMake.</string>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>Remote Dialer URL</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>rdialer</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

P.S. I've created my app using Qt Creator. I've also tried to create HelloWorld application with custom URL scheme in XCode and everything works fine.

Comment: Everything looks good from Safari but not from Firefox

Comment: Have you finished this problem?